# large mysql (innodb) database - slow query performance, disappearing tables and long time to restore backups

Tags: database, database-design, innodb, mysql

I've a database with 3 of the tables having rows in excess of 20 million each. I've used GUIDs as primary keys (unfortunately). Now our database is about 20GB and growing 5GB per month.

It takes about 2 hrs to take full backup of the database, and 30hrs to restore on a box with 4GB RAM.

We once have all the tables from database disappeared. other mysql databases in same server were alright except one - for which only data was disappeared leaving empty tables.

A select query (among many slow queries) - which get max of a date column in one of 20m table takes about 5 mins to return result. This query used pretty frequently.

What I'm looking answers for

1. recommended db design changes
2. ways to improved select query performance - max date column on 20m records
3. other queries' performance
4. how to go about handling future db growth

Thanks all for your attention.

Comment: For optimizing the select query, it might be helpful to have the relevant DB structure and query.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen setups of larger size (with `InnoDB` as storage engine and a `GUID` as a primary key), and there were no such problems.

> We once have all the tables from database disappeared. other mysql databases in same server were alright except one - for which only data was disappeared leaving empty tables.

The tables may seem empty if the system `LSN` has gone below the each page's `LSN`. This may happen if the `InnoDB` logfiles are corrupt. `InnoDB`, however, will issue a warning in this case.

> A select query (among many slow queries) - which get max of a date column in one of 20m table takes about 5 mins to return result. This query used pretty frequently.

Create an index on this column, the query will be instant.

Please post the exact query and I'll tell you how to create the best index.

I see no problem in the `DB` design as such, most probably it's something with your server.

Is it possible to reproduce this behavior on another server with a clean vanilla `MySQL` installation?

You may also want to try to split data between the tables. Set `innodb_file_per_table` and restore from the backup.

Answer (score 1):

A free alternaive to innodb hot backup is [Percona XtraBackup Tool](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start).

Answer (score 0):

For backup, you could use the [innodb hot backup](http://www.innodb.com/products/hot-backup/) tool.  This not only lets you do consistent backups while your database is up, but the restore is much faster than the one you're doing (I'm assuming mysqldump?).  It does cost money.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try Mydumper: http://www.mydumper.org/

It is a great tool and is free and open source